Search for a normal form of the "signless edge Laplacian matrix of a graph"
Let G be a graph with a finite set of vertices and a finite set of unoriented edges.
For simplicity, let us assume that there are no loops or multiple edges between any two vertices.
For certain reasons, I need to study the matrix
$$L = A \cdot A^T$$
where $A$ is the edge-vertex incidence matrix, so
$a_{ev} = 1$ if the edge $e$ is incident to vertex $v$ and $a_{ev} = 0$ otherwise.

The matrix $L$ might be viewed as an edge Laplacian, since the rows
and columns of $L$ are indexed by the set of edges.
The matrix $L$ is also a version of the signless Laplacian since the edges are not oriented.

My questions:
Has the matrix $L$ been studied before? Is there some established terminology for this matrix in the literature?
Let me note that, as far I could see, the classical notion of the Laplacian is the matrix $B \cdot B^T$, where the edges of $G$ are given an arbitrary orientation and $B$ is the vertex-edge incidence matrix with $b_{ve} = \pm 1$ depending on whether the edge $e$ starts or ends in the vertex $v$, and $b_{ve} = 0$ if the edge $e$ neither starts nor ends in $v$.
Edit/Update:
A few interesting questions are the following.
If $L$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-congruent to another symmetric integral matrix $L'$ of the same size (that is, there is a matrix $S \in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ with $S^T L S = L'$), they are also $\mathbb{R}$-congruent, so the signature of $L$ is equal to the signature of $L'$.

Is the converse true?
Is there a normal form for $L$ under $\mathbb{Z}$-congruence?

Let $L_G$ instead of $L$ denote the matrix associated to the graph $G$.

Given another simple undirected graph $G'$, when is $L_G$ $\mathbb{Z}$-congruent to $L_{G'}$?


Welcome to Math SE! Please do not change your question or add new questions to your post. If you have something new to ask, please make a different post and, if you wish, link it back to this one.

Sorry, I will take this into account in the future.

Yes, this matrix has been studied before. It is $2I + A_{L(G)}$ where $L(G)$ denotes the line graph of $G$ and $A_{L(G)}$ its adjacency matrix. A useful application in Spectral Graph Theory is that this yields a lower bound on the eigenvalues of line graphs. The matrix $AA^T$ is positive semi-definite, so its eigenvalues are nonnegative. Thus the eigenvalues of $A_{L(G)} = AA^T - 2I$ are at least $-2$.
See the YouTube video Signless Laplacian and line graphs by Steve Butler.

Thank You for the answer! This is exactly what I was looking for! (On a side note, one may use elementary row transformations to bring $A$ into a Gauss normal form (and simultaneous transposed transformations onto $A^T$) which then yields some normal form for $L$.)

You're welcome @CuriousInquirer :) If you find my answer sufficient, please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left.

I have already tried but I need a bit more reputation to be able to accept answers. When I have these points, I will do so!
